# How to handle connection status of sockets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart, tcp

I am building an app that requires to connect to a videoconference device in order to send call commands.

My problem comes when the device gets disconnected because it's powered off, cable disconnection, or any other issue. In that scenario, I am able to show it in the app thanks to the `vcfConnected` variable. However, I can never get the connection back to work (only by restarting the app, which is not desirable)

I am connecting to the device via dart socket like follows. The idea behind this implementation is to try to reconnect whenever there is a problem. However, is not working fine.

Does anybody know how to better handle the connection state?

Is it better to connect to the device each time I have to send a command and close the socket after that each time?

```
void connect(){
  Socket.connect('192.168.5.107', 55003).then((Socket socket) {
    sock = socket;
    vcfConnected = true;
    socket.listen((data) {
      String response = hex.encode(data);
      dataHandler(context, response);
    },
        onError: (error) => errorHandler(error),
        onDone: () => reconnect()
    );
    // Init protocol message
    sendCommand('&IPV');

    getMicMuteState();
    getReceiveVolume();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => checkVcfStatus());
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 15), onTimeout: () => onTimeout());

}

FutureOr<Null> onTimeout(){
  reconnect();
}

void reconnect(){
  print('VCF disconnected');
  vcfConnected = false;
  if (timer != null){
    timer.cancel();
  }
  if (sock != null) {
    sock.close();
  }
  sock = null;
  connect();
}

void errorHandler(, error){
  print('Error: $error');
  reconnect();
}

void checkVcfStatus() {
  sendCommand('?S');
}
```

Comment: @jsgalarrega did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @seyedaliAghamali nope...